# Raylib DrawTriangle() usage

Tags: c, raylib

I'm having trouble displaying  a triangle with Raylib's `DrawTriangle()` function.

### Minimum Reproducible Example

```c
#include <raylib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const unsigned int screenWidth = 1000;
    const unsigned int screenWidth = 1000;

    InitializeWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Amazing Window");

    // game loop
    while(! WindowShouldClose())
    {
        BeginDrawing();

        DrawTriangle(
            // triangle vertices
            {100, 10},
            {10, 100},
            {10, 10},

            // triangle color
            BLUE
        );

        EndDrawing();
    }
}
```

### Note

An example from [Raylib's website](https://www.raylib.com/examples.html) worked fine, so the arguments to `DrawTriangle` are probably to blame.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please note that C and C++ are different languages. Please only tag the language you are actually coding in.

Comment: I highly don't recommend mixing C and C++.  The C++ allows for operating overloading and compilers may use name mangling in order to make overloaded function names compatible with the C language names.  Also, C++ has references and exceptions.  This is possible to do in C, but gets tricky when trying to combine with C++.  Please update your language tags to the language (single) you are programming in.

Comment: Please add the definition of `TRIANGLE` to your post, as text.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `TRIANGLE` signifies the `WindowElement` type of `PlayerElement`, as when my code renders the element, it doesn't know what type the element data is. `TRIANGLE` is defined in an enumeration of possible element types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the arguments in counterclockwise did  the trick:

```c
DrawTriangle(
    {100, 10},  // point a
    {10, 100},  // point b
    {100, 100}, // point c
    BLACK       // triangle color
);
```